# Apply Custom Materials to GLTF Scenes in Bevy

Tags: rust, bevy

Hi I've made 3D game using Bevy framework.

I uploaded gltf file using `asset_server.load()` and got scene with `SceneBundle` like this :

```
fn spawn_gltf(
    mut commands: Commands,
    ass: Res<AssetServer>,
) {
    let my_gltf = ass.load("my.glb#Scene0");
    commands.spawn(SceneBundle {
        scene: my_gltf,
        transform: Transform::from_xyz(2.0, 0.0, -5.0),
        ..Default::default()
    });
}
```

Now I want to apply CustomMaterial with custom vertex and custom fragment to my SceneBundle. I found this [bevy shader example](https://bevyengine.org/examples/shader/shader-material/), but this showed applying CustomMaterial to `MaterialMeshBundle` not SceneBundle :

```
fn setup(
    mut commands: Commands,
    mut meshes: ResMut<Assets<Mesh>>,
    mut materials: ResMut<Assets<CustomMaterial>>,
    asset_server: Res<AssetServer>,
) {
    commands.spawn(MaterialMeshBundle {
        mesh: meshes.add(Mesh::from(shape::Cube { size: 1.0 })),
        transform: Transform::from_xyz(0.0, 0.5, 0.0),
        material: materials.add(CustomMaterial {
            color: Color::BLUE,
            color_texture: Some(asset_server.load("branding/icon.png")),
            alpha_mode: AlphaMode::Blend,
        }),
        ..default()
    });
}

impl Material for CustomMaterial {
    fn fragment_shader() -> ShaderRef {
        "shaders/custom_material.wgsl".into()
    }

    fn alpha_mode(&self) -> AlphaMode {
        self.alpha_mode
    }
}

// This is the struct that will be passed to your shader
#[derive(AsBindGroup, TypeUuid, Debug, Clone)]
#[uuid = "f690fdae-d598-45ab-8225-97e2a3f056e0"]
pub struct CustomMaterial {
    #[uniform(0)]
    color: Color,
    #[texture(1)]
    #[sampler(2)]
    color_texture: Option<Handle<Image>>,
    alpha_mode: AlphaMode,
}
```

What I want to do is that uploading glTF scene by asset_server.load() with its material and then applying CustomMaterial with another funcion. Is there any way?

Many Thanks.

Comment: [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75801912/how-to-modify-material-property-in-bevy) might help you. Unfortunately it is not a very clean solution...

Comment: So, effectively, you want to extract the mesh data from the glTF scene and create a `MaterialMeshBundle` from it, which then can be customized with your `CustomMaterial`?

Comment: @JishanShaikh yes that can be a way, but what I want to do is that uploading glTF scene with its material and then applying CustomMaterial with another funcion.